# PHP: Serve unfinished file for download

Tags: php, download, partial

I'm creating large file on demand. It can be video file from IP camera or zip or something else. For example:

`avconv -i http://CAM_IP:3000/T-8395-273-259 -c:v libx264 -movflags faststart -an output.mp4`

Is it possible to serve this file to download during this process using PHP?

Comment: If this process can output to stdout instead of a file, you can easily pipe it through to the client directly.

Comment: OK, maybe, didn't test it, but what about HTTP headers?

Comment: You can send any HTTP headers you want, then start that program and pipe its output to PHP's output.